# usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1 after installing graphics drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, usb, graphics

I have install Ubuntu Desktop LTS (Latest version I think it is 16.04) onto my main computer which runs a Nvidia graphics card and after I select the additional drivers for Nvidia via System settings and restart I get this message saying "usb_submit_urb(ctrl)" failed: -1 then it goes to Busybox.

I've read things saying you need a live USB stick which I can't do since my main pc is kind of busted and I'm writing this on my phone.

The USB stick where I installed Ubuntu onto my pc only goes to the installer once selected.

Specs: Nvidia Geforce GTX 950 (not overclocked)

Drivers: Trying to get the latest drivers.

Comment: What Nvidia graphics and what drivers?

Comment: Nvidia Geforce GTX 950
and I was trying to get the drivers through the additional drivers tab in the update settings.

Comment: *What Nvidia graphics and what drivers?* Both the hardware info and drivers version should be added to your question, not just comments. Please edit and add the relevant information.

Comment: @yetenszi, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I dont think this is Nvidia specific issue, since i get same error message for intel hd graphics 4000 driver installation